# Select the largest number from MYSQL Table with added Prefix

Tags: mysql

I have a table that unfortunately, I can't alter in any way and have to work with what I have.

The mysql table has a field labeled, "customer_id". It has 2 prefixed letters with a 4-value numerical number.

EX: 
BI8392

HE8492

WO1293

How can I select the largest numerical value with a certain prefix? For example, assume that I wanted to select the largest number with a prefix of HE. How can I select that value?

Any help is absolutely appreciated. I've been stuck for a while now.

Comment: Yes, they are left padded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since all values left padded you can do

```sql
SELECT RIGHT(MAX(customer_id), 4) max_val
  FROM table1
 WHERE customer_id LIKE 'HE%'
```

Make sure that you have an index on `customer_id` which you probably do based on a name of the column. `LIKE` will most likely use it.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad6dd/1)** demo

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT LEFT(customer_id,2) AS PREFIX,
       MAX(RIGHT(customer_id,4)) AS MAX
FROM table1
GROUP BY LEFT(customer_id,2)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9376/5)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`customer_id` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`customer_id`)
VALUES
    ('DD1234'),
    ('DD1222'),
    ('EE2345'),
    ('EE6789')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT LEFT(customer_id,2) AS PREFIX,
       MAX(RIGHT(customer_id,4)) AS MAX
FROM table1
GROUP BY LEFT(customer_id,2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9376/5/0)**:

```
| PREFIX |  MAX |
|--------|------|
|     DD | 1234 |
|     EE | 6789 |
```

EDIT :

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(customer_id,4)) AS MAX
FROM table1
GROUP BY LEFT(customer_id,2)
WHERE LEFT(customer_id,2) = 'HE'
```

Comment: @inflagranti what do you mean?

Comment: @inflagranti.  OP is looking to get the MAX value, not list the values numerically...  Also if you are looking for a specific max change the `GROUP BY` to a `WHERE` clause that fits your needs.

Comment: Yeah, there are dozens of these prefixed letters. Is there any way to just return the 'HE' prefix with the largest value? This is absolutely wonderful btw Fabien. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Forget my question, I forgot it was always 4 letters numerical value. Because in general the maximum of a variable length string representing a number is not equal to the maximum number.

Comment: @OP get rid of the GROUP BY clause and replace it with `WHERE LEFT(customer_id,2) = 'HE'`

Answer (score 1):

USE:

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(customer_id,4)) AS max fROM table_name 
    WHERE LEFT(customer_id,2)='HE';
```

Comment: Forgot the where clause for 'HE'.

Answer (score 0):

If your prefixes have the same length, you could do:

Ex.

```
SELECT MID(column_name,start[,length]) FROM table_name;
```

Filled out:

```
SELECT MID(customer_id,2,4) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Document;
+--------+-------------+
| DataID | Description |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 | BI8392      |
|      2 | HE8492      |
|      3 | HE8493      |
|      4 | HE8490      |
+--------+-------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(Description,3)) FROM Document
WHERE SUBSTR(Description,1,2) = 'HE';
```

Returns:

```
+----------------------------+
| MAX(SUBSTR(Description,3)) |
+----------------------------+
| 8493                       |
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do a substring and then to ORDER BY, you will need to **cast it to a decimal** (else it will order by Varchar, Example 999 will be greater than 1000)

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(MyColumn,3, LEN(MyColumn) - 2 ) 
  FROM dbo.MyTable
  ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(MyColumn,3, LEN(MyColumn) - 2 ) as decimal) DESC;
```

*The number 3 above is if the Prefix is 2 characters long.
Consequently, the number 2 is to find the length of string without Prefix.*