# Select highest number from a MySQL Database column with 0 padding?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to Select the highest number from a MySQL Database column when the value can have 0's padded in front if needed.

Numbers start at `000001` and go up as high as possible as our record set grows.

Right now we have around 14,xxx records and when I run this SQL...

```
SELECT MAX( designnumber_c ) 
FROM d1_designs_cstm
LIMIT 1
```

The result is a record with the Value of `009999` so the next number and up is not recognized as the highest number.

How can I make sure to return the highest value number?  If it matter, the column is not a `INT` but instead a `VARCHAR` was this way before I had it.

Please help?

Comment: Those numbers are sorted properly in ASCII, are you saying that numbers such as `12,000` exist, but you still only get `9,999`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try type-casting first?

> SELECT MAX(cast(designnumber_c as unsigned)) from d1_designs_cstm LIMIT 1

I just did a quick test and cast('009999' as unsigned) returned a numeric representation of 9999 so I would think it should work.

Comment: This does work...I simply have never used any sort of "casting" in SQL only in PHP and Ruby...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution: you can order your result in DESCENDING and select only one row. This can be done by:

```
SELECT designnumber_c FROM d1_designs_cstm
ORDER BY CAST(`designnumber_c` AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 1
```

But its better to solve issue by changing datatype of `designnumber_c` to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX( changed_to_int ) 
FROM(
SELECT CAST(designnumber_c AS UNSIGNED) as changed_to_int
FROM d1_designs_cstm
) as t
```

not sure how efficient this would be but it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This page should probably help.  Especially if you ALWAYS have 6 digit numbers.
[Select the largest number from MYSQL Table with added Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600646/select-the-largest-number-from-mysql-table-with-added-prefix)

This does work while leaving the leading zeros in place. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf0a8/1)

```
SELECT RIGHT(MAX(designnumber_c), 6) max_val
FROM d1_designs_cstm
LIMIT 1
```

Hope this helps.